# How to use a symbol from SVG file in the HTML

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend

I have a https://github.com/rajamunuma/test/blame/main/test.svg file with below content

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
<symbol id="icon-checkmark" viewBox="0 0 16 13">
    <title>checkmark icon</title>
    <path d="M13.189,0,6.054,7.258,2.811,3.9,0,6.825l3.243,3.358h0L6.054,13,16,2.817Z" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
</symbol>
<svg>
```

I would like to use the use the symbol "icon-checkmark" in the html file directly. Something like below

```
<img src="https://github.com/rajamunuma/test/blame/main/test.svg#icon-checkmark" />
<img src="https://github.com/rajamunuma/test/blame/main/test.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,0,16,13))" />
```

Note: I cannot directly copy the content of svg file into my html file. I want to refer to svg file path and include it on the html page.

Comment: you render symbols via the use tag, not img so you'd need to put some SVG in the html file that has a use tag that references the external symbol.

Comment: Please read about [How SVG Fragment Identifiers Work](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define **symbol** icon like below snippet.
I hope below snippet will help you a lot.

*Helpful link:*
https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/

```css
.icon {
    stroke: unset;
    stroke-width: 0px;
    fill: currentColor;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    vertical-align: -0.15em;
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon">
   <use href="#icon-checkmark"></use>
</svg>



<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="icon-checkmark" viewBox="0 0 16 13">
      <path d="M13.189,0,6.054,7.258,2.811,3.9,0,6.825l3.243,3.358h0L6.054,13,16,2.817Z" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
  </symbol>
<svg>
```